# How to create a copy of a struct only having interface it implements and it's value

Tags: go, struct, interface

Let's say I have this `A` struct that implements `Setter` interface:

```golang
type Setter interface {
    Set(key string, value string)
}

type A struct {
    m map[string]string
}

func (a *A) Set(key string, value string) {
    a.m[key] = value
}
```

And I have one different struct that holds some implementation of `Setter` interface

```golang
type Holder struct {
    val Setter
}

h := Holder{
    val: &A{ map[string]string{} },
}
```

What i need is to get a copy of the `h.val` struct with all values saved.

I have already tried the following solution but it did not work, resulting with `panic: assignment to entry in nil map`

*(We have defined the map when initiallizing `h`, so by running `h.val.Set(k, v)` we won't get any errors)*

```golang
l := reflect.New(
    reflect.ValueOf(h.val).Elem().Type(),
).Interface().(Setter)

l.Set("A", "B")
```

How can I create a copy of a struct without knowing which fields it consists of, only knowing the interface it implements and having it's value in a variable?

*p.s. Adding `Clone` method to `Setter` interface is not a preferred solution*

Comment: `reflect.New`, like the builtin `new` only initializes the root type. i.e. if you give it `A` you'll get back initialized `*A` but the `m` field will be uninitialized, well it will be initialized to its "zero" value which, in some cases is ok, but in the case of maps it is `nil`, hence the panic. Doing deep copies is one thing, doing "deep" initializations, although similar, is another. In both cases you'll have to use `reflect` to traverse the structure from the root to the leaves and copy/initialize each individually. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding Clone method to Setter interface is not a preferred solution

in all generality, since only the `Setter` implementation knows how it should be "cloned", there isn't much choice.

For example : should "cloning" an `A` struct create a new struct pointing at the same mapping ? or should it duplicate the mapping ?

If your intention is really to clone, you probably want the second, but you can see it will quickly fall outside the scope of a simple `reflect` operation.

---

If your code actually only deals with `A` structs, you may pass explicit `A` values. You will probably still need a `.Clone()` method or a `Clone(a *A)` function.

---

If your only issue is that a zero value for `A` is invalid, you can fix `Set()` :

```
func (a *A) Set(key string, value string) {
    if a.m == nil {
        a.m = make(map[string]string)
    }
    a.m[key] = value
}
```

Comment: 1. Not only ```A``` structs, but any struct that implements ```Setter``` interface. 
2. If deep copy is not possible without a specific ```Clone``` method, is there a way to initialize it with reflect by giving all the fileds their's empty values, such as automatically setting ```Holder.val``` as an empty map rather that nil value?

Comment: There is, but will it be what you need ? do you need a `Clone()` or a `New()` function ?

Comment: A `Clone()` function will probably not create an empty object

Comment: the ```Clone()``` function is more preferrable, but if it's not possible, ```New()``` would be good enough